# Simulate BLE broadcast role using BT classic?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I understand that at present only a few android devices have chipsets which support BLE peripheral mode.  For my application I want my device to act as a beacon but I don't care about power consumption.  Is it possible to use regular BT to broadcast advertisement data, so nearby phones running BLE in central mode will "hear" that advertisement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldnt work because Bluetooth Low Energy works so different compared to the "old" BR/EDR mode. There are even changes in the Physical Layer as BLE uses a different channel map and protocols.

If you had access to your Bluetooth 2.1 controller on a very, very low level (i.e. Firmware), with alot of work you might succeed in sneaking out an advertisement on the right frequency though. Thats speculation though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with Android Lollipop. Check the Bluetooth Low Energy section in Android 5.0 API:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html

```
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) 
getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
BluetoothLeAdvertiser myBluetoothLeAdvertiser =  myBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser ();
myBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising (AdvertiseSettings settings, AdvertiseData advertiseData, AdvertiseCallback callback);
```

Comment: I think this is just the standard way to start a BLE advertisement, and from what I've read very few chipsets support this at the moment. Per my original question I'm wondering if there's a way to send an advertisement using BT classic, (without the low-energy benefit of course).